# Doctrine expected Lexer::T_FROM, got '>'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

(Symfony 3.2.7)

I've got this query created inside repository:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select($qb->expr()->gte('c.createdDate', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()').' AS HIDDEN x');
$qb->orderBy('x');
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

It is generating this DQL:

```
SELECT c.createdDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS HIDDEN x 
FROM App\CatalogBundle\Entity\Company c 
ORDER BY x ASC
```

And also... it is generating this error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 21: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '>'

What could be wrong here?

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @bishop answer, I managed to create a solution on my problem with creating a custom Doctrine DQL function. Configuration:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                DATES_COMPARE: AppBundle\DQL\DatesCompareFunction
```

And here is what mentioned class contains:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

class DatesCompareFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    /* @var Query\AST\Node  */
    public $param1;

    /* @var Query\AST\Node  */
    public $param2;

    /* @var Query\AST\Node  */
    public $param3;

    /** @inheritdoc */
    public function getSql(Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf(
            'CASE (%s %s %s) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END',
            $this->param1->dispatch($sqlWalker),
            $this->param2,
            $this->param3->dispatch($sqlWalker)
        );
    }

    /** @inheritdoc */
    public function parse(Query\Parser $parser): void
    {
        $parser->match(Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->param1 = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Query\Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->param2 = $parser->ComparisonOperator();

        $parser->match(Query\Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->param3 = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

So all is working properly for the following DQL:

```
SELECT DATES_COMPARE(c.subscriptionEndDate, >, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS x 
FROM App\CatalogBundle\Entity\Company c 
ORDER BY x DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is valid SQL, but remember: SQL != DQL. Checking the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) for DQL, we see the `SELECT` has this BNF:

> SelectExpression        ::= (IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression | NewObjectExpression) [["AS"] ["HIDDEN"] AliasResultVariable]

But the `>=` operator appears *only* in ConditionalExpression:

> ConditionalExpression       ::= ConditionalTerm {"OR" ConditionalTerm}*
>   ConditionalTerm             ::= ConditionalFactor {"AND" ConditionalFactor}*
>   ConditionalFactor           ::= ["NOT"] ConditionalPrimary
>   ConditionalPrimary          ::= SimpleConditionalExpression | "(" ConditionalExpression ")"
>   SimpleConditionalExpression ::= ComparisonExpression | BetweenExpression | LikeExpression |
>                                   InExpression | NullComparisonExpression | ExistsExpression |
>                                   EmptyCollectionComparisonExpression | CollectionMemberExpression |
>                                   InstanceOfExpression
>
> ComparisonExpression     ::= ArithmeticExpression ComparisonOperator ( QuantifiedExpression | ArithmeticExpression )
>
> ComparisonOperator       ::= "=" | "<" | "<=" | "<>" | ">" | ">=" | "!="

Since `SelectExpression` does not include `ConditionalExpression`, you're getting a lexing error.

To accomplish what you want, you'll need a custom function. See ["Adding your own functions to the DQL language"](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language) for how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I managed to create a proper solution and I've added it to the content of my Question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do this condition in a where(), addWhere() or orWhere()
method instead

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select('c')
    ->addWhere($qb->expr()->gte('c.createdDate', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()').' AS HIDDEN x')
    ->orderBy('x')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;
```